# C# - Visual Studio is forced terminated when UserControl is added on other control

Tags: c#, user-controls, .net-3.5

.NET framework 3.5
I make a simple UserControl consist of label1 and label2.

I override Font attribute.

```
public override Font Font  
{  
   get  
   {  
       return this.Font;
   }
   set
   {
       label1.Font = value;
       label2.Font = value;
   }
}
```

Then I added the UserControl on other form.
howerver visual studio was forced terminated.
what matter is in this code?

Comment: See marked duplicate for an explanation of the crash. In your case, most likely you should change the getter to `return base.Font;` Noting, however, that your implementation makes the getter and setter asymmetric. Maybe it would be better to make the getter `return label1.Font;` instead, on the assumption that `label1` and `label2` will always have the same `Font` value.

Comment: @PeterDuniho  Didn't know how to call. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to override setaccessor, use this:

```
public override Font Font  
{  
  set
  {
    label1.Font = value;
    label2.Font = value;
  }
}
```

And never call

```
get
   {
     return this.Font;
   }
```

because it's recursive call and it causes your crash problem.

Comment: Thanks you. I change "get { return this.font; }" to "get { return _font; }" and add class variable "private Font _font;". Is it okay? And Is "get { return base.font } enabled?

Comment: You could {return  label1.Font }; or Add base.Font = value; into set accessor, and return base.Font

Comment: Okay, Thank you. um.. Is "{ get; set; }" same "{ get{ return base.Font} set { base.Font = value } }"?

Answer (score 0):

This is an infinite loop! If you try to get Font (auto-)property, it will try to get Font (auto-)property and so on...

```
public override Font Font{  
   get  
   {  
       return this.Font;  ←This calls itself
   }
```